# MongoDB delete all documents by or

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `calendar` document like below

```
calendar: [
 {days: {
  1: [],
  2: ['surprise'],
  3: [],
  ...
 }},
 {days: {
  1: [],
  2: [],
  3: ['test'],
  ...
 }}
]
```

I'm trying to find words wherever are they then pull them from array. Here's my code:

```
var words = ['test']
Calendar.update(
    {$or: [
      {"calendar.days.1": {$in: words}},
      {"calendar.days.2": {$in: words}}
    ]},
    {$pull:
      {$or: 
       {"calendar.days.1": {$in: words}},
       {"calendar.days.2": {$in: words}}
      }
    },
    {multi: true}
  )
```

First part is working correctly. It finds documents which have words. But in the second part it's not deleting the words from array. Returns that log:
`{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

Any helps?

Comment: Is `days` an array or an object with keys 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Sorry. Days is not array. It is object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$[]` positional operator after `calendar` field in update part,

```
var words = ['test'];
await Calendar.update(
  {
    $or: [
      { "calendar.days.1": { $in: words } },
      { "calendar.days.2": { $in: words } }
    ]
  },
  {
    $pull: {
      "calendar.$[].days.1": { $in: words },
      "calendar.$[].days.2": { $in: words }
    }
  },
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/36ECvZX6hvc)